# Метод indexOf не видит символ в строке

Tags: java, строки, парсер, indexof

Пытаюсь узнать индекс тире в строке, сам символ метод contain в строке видит и выдает true, но indexOf выдает -1. Проблема возникает только в той части строки, которая идет после NNBSP(присутствует на сайте, который пытаюсь пропарсить), от него я избавился, но проблема не исчезла. Как можно решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

```
 @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test()
    {
        String money = "400 000 – 800 000 ₸";
        money = money.replaceAll(" ", "");
        /*if(money.contains("от") || money.contains("до"))
        {
            money = money.substring(3, money.length() - 1);
        }*/
        if(money.contains("–"))
        {
            System.out.println(money.indexOf("-"));
        }
        System.out.println(money);
        return "main";
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто у вас в коде два разных знака `-`, это легко проверяется поиском по этой странице с вопросом прямо в браузере. Я пометил комментариями, где какой знак используется.

```
String money = "400 000 – 800 000 ₸"; // Среднее тире (En Dash) &#8211;
...
if(money.contains("–")) // Среднее тире (En Dash) &#8211;
{
    System.out.println(money.indexOf("-")); // Обычный дефис, код 45
}
```

И таких внешне похожих знаков на странице может быть много разных. Бывают и разные виды пробелов, например.